# How to replace cells in a column with Chinese characters based on list of translations?

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am a VBA newbie here. Ideally, I would like to put together a macro that will scan a specific column for certain Chinese phrases and translate them per a list of translations.

I've started with kind of a primitive find and replace via an Activecell.value loop per my friend's suggestion, but it won't work because VBA doesn't allow for Chinese characters.

```
sub Translate()

ActiveCell.Select ("A2")

Dim r As Integer      ' Number of rows

'   ****************************** Input ******************************

'  Count rows "r" & Indent

'   Use Loop

Do

    r = r + 1
    If ActiveCell.Value = "??" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Apple"
    Else
        If ActiveCell.Value = "??" Then
           ActiveCell.Value = "Banana"
    End If

'   Move Cursor
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
'   End Loop
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Here's the logic I would want the macro to follow:

1. select a specific column as range
2. check value of cell
3. if value of cell = specific Chinese phrase (likely from another sheet or index)
4. replace value with specified translation phrase
5. continue down the column until blank cell is reached, then end macro

For example,

```
   A
1 **Fruit**
2 赛伍
3 香蕉
```

gets checked against reference sheet or index:

```
   A    B
1 赛伍 apple
2 香蕉 banana
```

so that the end result is:

```
    A
1 **Fruit**
2 apple
3 banana
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I do not think my question is a duplicate to "declaring a unicode string in vba in excel" because ideally the macro would function based on reading cell values outside of the code

ex:

```
' if Sheet0!A2 matches Sheet1!A2, replace Sheet0!A2 with Sheet1!B2
```

Comment: Edit: I do not think my question is a duplicate to "declaring a unicode string in vba in excel" because ideally the macro would function based on reading cell values outside of the code

ex:

' if Sheet0!A2 matches Sheet1!A2, replace Sheet0!A2 with Sheet1!B2

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the two sheets are `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. You may use a for loop to iterate the cells of the first column on Sheet1 and then use the [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method to look for a match in `Sheet2`.

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Dim currentCell As Range, foundChineseCell As Range, foundEnglishCell As Range
        Set currentCell = Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
        Set foundChineseCell = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Find(currentCell.Value)
        If Not foundChineseCell Is Nothing Then
            Set foundEnglishCell = foundChineseCell.Offset(0, 1)
            currentCell.Value = foundEnglishCell.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed and beautiful response - unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work. Ideally, it'd be nicer if the macro checked a list that I didn't have to open or move into the sheet - I'll probably need to simply find a different work around for what I'm trying to accomplish, I guess.

Comment: @MorganThomas _"I couldn't get it to work"_ As you can see in the gif, it works as expected. I can't tell you what's wrong unless I see your code.

Comment: _"Ideally, it'd be nicer if the macro checked a list that I didn't have to open or move into the sheet"_ Do you mean you want to hardcode the list of words in your code? Because that's what I thought you wanted to do at the beginning and that you couldn't do it because the editor doesn't support Unicode characters so I suggested a duplicate post but then you said you want to put the list of words in a sheet, right?